# Disabling a Unity input action map in its own callback causes an error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
 
public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private InputDeviceController _UserInputDevice;
    private void Awake() {
        _UserInputDevice = new InputDeviceController();
        _UserInputDevice.IAM_One.Up_IAMOne.canceled += CallbackContext => Up_IAMOne();
        _UserInputDevice.IAM_Two.Up_IAMTwo.canceled += CallbackContext => Up_IAMTwo();
        _UserInputDevice.IAM_One.Enable();
    }
 
    private void Up_IAMOne() {
        Debug.Log("Up_IAMOne");
        _UserInputDevice.IAM_One.Disable();
        _UserInputDevice.IAM_Two.Enable();
    }
 
    private void Up_IAMTwo() {
        Debug.Log("Up_IAMTwo");
        _UserInputDevice.IAM_Two.Disable();
        _UserInputDevice.IAM_One.Enable();
    }
}
```

Hooking up the code above with the new Unity input system will trigger a stack overflow error. The use case for this code is a bit odd, but I'm not sure why it's causing an error. Am I miss understanding how the new input system works, or is there something else going on related to how I implemented the callback methods?

Error Message: StackOverflowException while executing 'canceled' callbacks of 'IAM_One/Up_IAMOne

Comment: Is `InputDeviceController` something you implemented? Could you post the code? It sounds like the `_UserInputDevice.IAM_One.Disable();` internally also triggers `_UserInputDevice.IAM_One.Up_IAMOne.canceled`

Comment: @derHugo InputDeviceController is the name for the C# class that is auto-generated when using Unity's Input Action system. I haven't changed the file in any way, so I don't believe the error would reside in that class, unless it's a bug with Unity itself when it generates the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue with Unity's Input System and has been fixed in Input System 1.1.0-preview.1 and above, available in Unity 2019.4.0f1 and above